# tikz diagram combination (with dia output)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to create this diagram:

[image: diagram]

I managed to create the boxes with this code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm, auto,]
\node[punkt] (market) {Update tree};
\node[ above=of market] (dummy) {};
\node[punkt, above=of dummy] (dummy3) {Draw $\Delta t$};
\node[punkt, right=of dummy] (t) {Draw $\rho | \Delta t, y$};
\node[punkt, left=of dummy] (comparison) {Compare with observed tree};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

and creating the arrows in dia, I could even get the latex code for the arrows with a very complex generated code (see in the very end, I do not know if I should add it).

But when I combine both codes I get errors and cannot make the plot. Any help is appreciated.

```
\ifx\du\undefined
  \newlength{\du}
\fi
\setlength{\du}{15\unitlength}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgftransformxscale{1.000000}
\pgftransformyscale{-1.000000}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% image rendering not supported\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\pgfsetarrowsend{stealth}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-403.700000\du,42.500000\du)--(-403.700000\du,42.500000\du);
}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\pgfsetarrowsend{stealth}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-417.949962\du}{9.949999\du}}
\pgfpatharc{269}{143}{1.429551\du and 1.429551\du}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\pgfsetarrowsend{stealth}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-411.049840\du}{13.600048\du}}
\pgfpatharc{287}{251}{7.759989\du and 7.759989\du}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\pgfsetarrowsend{stealth}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-415.650500\du}{14.649839\du}}
\pgfpatharc{108}{70}{7.125443\du and 7.125443\du}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\pgfsetarrowsend{stealth}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-419.057248\du}{15.891588\du}}
\pgfpatharc{196}{113}{1.974003\du and 1.974003\du}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\pgfsetarrowsend{stealth}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-416.112627\du}{12.991865\du}}
\pgfpatharc{115}{2}{1.629642\du and 1.629642\du}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\pgfsetarrowsend{stealth}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-408.800310\du}{18.349868\du}}
\pgfpatharc{114}{-118}{4.669774\du and 4.669774\du}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
}
```

Comment: I think it is much easier to create it from the scratch in tikz... Also it would be better to add a running code... See MWE... I don't know where to fint this punkt and I can not run it

Comment: Please complete your code so that we can copy-paste-compile it. Right now, we can't know how to complete it as we don't know how you've defined things. And why are you creating the arrows in another programme rather than just drawing them in Ti*k*Z?

Comment: Suggest to use `\documentclass[standalone]` instead of `article` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tikz only:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{
  punkt/.style={
    draw,
    rounded corners = 2pt,
    align=center,
    text width=2.5cm
  },
  %
  myarrows/.style={
    ->, 
    shorten <=2pt, 
    shorten >=2pt
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm, auto,]
\node[punkt] (market) {Update tree};
\node[above=of market] (dummy) {};
\node[punkt, above=of dummy] (dummy3) {Draw $\Delta t$};
\node[punkt, right=of dummy] (t) {Draw $\rho | \Delta t, y$};
\node[punkt, left=of dummy] (comparison) {Compare with observed tree};

\draw[myarrows] (market.east) arc (225:495:2);
\draw[myarrows] (comparison.east) to [bend right] (t.west);
\draw[myarrows] (t.west) to [bend right] (comparison.east);

\draw[myarrows] (comparison.north east) to [bend right] (dummy3.south);
\draw[myarrows] (dummy3.west) to [bend right] (comparison.north) ;


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]